# MongoDb updating existing documents with sequence/unique id?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to update existing documents with a unique id

When I execute the following function,
I am not sure what is right scope for the internal counter?

```
db.myDocs.find().forEach(function(doc){
    db.myDocs.update({_id :  doc._id}, {$set: {
        unique_id : COUNTER_HERE?
    }});     
   COUNTER++;
});
```

One solution will be to create additional count collection but I would like to avoid that if possible.

**EDIT**

unique id per this for loop only.

Comment: One way to keep a counter would be to just put it in the "global" scope of that file. That said, when you restart your server, your counter would start back at 0.

Comment: I just need this to run once, how do I define this counter in global scope?

Comment: @Pytth - any chance of resetting to 0 kinda breaks the notion of unique id.

Comment: Does it need to be a counter, or just a unique id? If just unique, you can generate a guid.

Comment: preferably a number  as string like 0005 0006 .... 00555

Comment: You can use mongo DB * next sequence *  I forgot the name of the plugin but I found one.  Seems you are trying to generate unique sequential id like SQL.

Comment: I found the solution here ...    osman if you edit your answer to add the code i will accept it.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `{new : true}` if you add value into new property in doc and `{multi: true}` for multiple documents update as the option.

Comment: In their loop, they're only updating one document at a time; no need for `{multi:true}`.

Comment: If the counter is okay, I mean once run it and it increases then `{new : true}` should work.